# Display jquery gridView in jsp

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is my userDetailsHOme.jsp . Here I have designed one button "settings".
Once i click on "settings" a dialog popup opens which has few textfields and a continue button to submit the fields. 
On submitting the button  i am mapping it to an action named as "BestStrategyAction", which in turn returns a grid.jsp file.
In BestStrategyAction class before reuturn statement i have printed SYSO , to confirm everything is executed.
Problem is that code executes till Syso but dosn't display the grid .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<sj:head jqueryui="true" />
<s:head />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/OptionsTrader2/struts/js/base/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/js/jquery-ui-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/js/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/js/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/js/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/OptionsTrader2/img/favicon.ico" />
<link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet" href="/OptionsTrader2/css/absolution/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/OptionsTrader2/css/jquery_layout.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/OptionsTrader2/css/tipsy.css" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<body>
 <div class="ui-layout-center">
 </div>
 <div id="toolbar" class="ui-layout-north">
  <button id="settingsButton" onclick="$('#settingsDialog').dialog('open')"
        title="Click to customize your strategy settings.">Settings
 </button>
</div>

<div id="settingsDialog"
    style="font-size: 11px;" class="ui-layout-content ui-widget-content">
    <form id="changeSetting" name="changeSetting">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="underlyingSelect">Select Underlying</label></td>
             <td>
                <sj:select href="underlyingAction" id="underlyingName" name="underlyingName" list="underlyingList"  cssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />                      
            </td>


        </tr>           
        <tr>
        <td><label for="enterinvestment">Enter Investment Amount in Rs. *</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="100000"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="enterlosslimit">Enter Loss limit *</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="losslimit" id="losslimit" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="200"/></td>
        <td>%</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="monthIndex">Select Month</label></td>
        <td><select id="monthIndex" name="monthIndex" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <option value="0">Current</option>
                <option value="1">Next</option>
                <option value="2">Far</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="strategyType">Select Strategy</label></td>          
        <td><select id="strategyType" name="strategyType" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <option value="4">All</option>
                <option value="0">Neutral</option>
                <option value="1">Volatile</option>
                <option value="2">Bearish</option>
                <option value="3">Bullish</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><label for="maxNoLegs">Legs in Strategy</label></td>            
        <td><select id="maxNoLegs" name="maxNoLegs" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" >

                <option value="4">Upto 4 Legs</option>
                <option value="3">Upto 3 Legs</option>
                <option value="2">Upto 2 Legs</option>      
        </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><label for="riskReward">Select Risk:Reward</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="risk" id="risk" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" size="2"/>:
            <input type="text" name="reward" id="reward" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" size="2"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="ulRangeFrom">Underlying Range :</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ulFrom" id="ulFrom" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all rangeClass" size=4/> To
            <input type="text" name="ulTo" id="ulTo" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all rangeClass" size=4/></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="expectedROIPerc">Expected Return % p.a.</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="expectedROIPerc" id="expectedROIPerc" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="11.52" size=4/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="otm"/><label for="check">OTM and ATM only</label> 
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="deltaHedgeReqdd"/><label for="check"> Delta Hedge</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="unlimitedLossCheck"/><label for="check">Disable unlimited loss  </label>
            </td>
             <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="check"/><label for="check">Futures</label>
            </td>
        </tr>               
</table>
    </div>
 <script>
  $("#settingsDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "<strong>Change Setting</strong>",
        height: 350,
        width: 500,
        position: "center",
        resizable: true,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Continue': function() {

            var amount = $("#amount").val();
            var losslimit = $("#losslimit").val();
            var monthIndex = $("#monthIndex").val();
            var type = $("#strategyType").val();
            var derivativetype = $("#check").is(':checked');
            var underlyingName =  $("#underlyingName").val();
           //alert("UL " + $("#underlyingList").val() + " " + $("#underlyingList").selected().value());
            var risk = $("#risk").val();
            var reward = $("#reward").val();
            var riskReward = parseFloat(risk)/parseFloat(reward);
            var ulFrom = $("#ulFrom").val();
            var ulTo = $("#ulTo").val();
            var otm = $("#otm").is(':checked');

            var expectedROIPerc = $("#expectedROIPerc").val();
            var maxNoLegs = $("#maxNoLegs").val();
            var unlimitedLoss = $("#unlimitedLossCheck").is(':checked');
            var deltaHedgeReqd = $("#deltaHedgeReqdd").is(':checked');

            var dataString = '&amount='+ amount+ '&monthIndex=' + monthIndex+'&type='+type+'&derivativetype='+derivativetype+'&losslimit='+losslimit+'&riskReward='+riskReward+'&underlyingName='+underlyingName+'&ulFrom='+ulFrom+'&ulTo='+ulTo+'&otm='+otm+'&expectedROIPerc='+expectedROIPerc+'&maxNoLegs='+maxNoLegs+'&disableUnlimitedLoss='+unlimitedLoss+'&deltaHedgeReqd='+deltaHedgeReqd; //+ '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&monthIndex=' + monthIndex;
                if(amount==''|| monthIndex=='' || losslimit=='')// || username=='' || password=='' 
                {
                    $('.success').fadeOut(500).hide();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(500).show();
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "bestStrategies",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(){
                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                        $('#gridtable0').setGridParam({datatype:'json'});
                        $('#gridtable0').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
                      }
                    });
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
                return false;

            }, 
            'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            }, 
            },

});
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the my BestStrategiesAction mapped to the submit button.

```
 @Action(value = "bestStrategies", results = { @Result(location = "grid.jsp", name = "success") })
public String execute() throws Exception {
    log.debug("==============best Strategy invoked :wih url :");
    log.info("best Strategy invoked :wih url :");
    StrategyService strategyService = strategyServiceFactory.getObject();
    user = ((OptionsUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserr();
    user = Userr.findUserr(user.getId());
    List<Account> accountList = user.getAccounts();
    BrokerageSlab brokerageSlab = user.getBrokerageslab();

    log.debug("amount :"+amount+" monthIndex :"+monthIndex+" losslimit :"+losslimit+" nd underlyingName :"+underlyingName);

    System.out.println("User name :"+user.getName()+" account id :"+accountList.get(0).getId());



    Date date = new Date();
    if(amount == ""){
        amount = "0";
    }
    int investingAmount = Integer.parseInt(amount);
    int strategyType = Integer.parseInt(type);
    int selectedmonth = Integer.parseInt(monthIndex);
    boolean derivativeType = Boolean.parseBoolean(derivativetype);
    int currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    int userlossLimit = Integer.parseInt(losslimit);
    double riskRewardRatio = riskReward.equals("NaN")?0:Double.parseDouble(riskReward);
    double ulRangeFrom = ulFrom.equals("")?0:Double.parseDouble(ulFrom);
    double ulRangeTo = ulTo.equals("")?0:Double.parseDouble(ulTo);
    boolean otmSelected = Boolean.parseBoolean(otm);
    double expectedROI = expectedROIPerc.equals("")?0:Double.parseDouble(expectedROIPerc);
    int maxNoLegsStrategy = maxNoLegs.equals("")?4:Integer.parseInt(maxNoLegs);
    boolean isUnlimitedLoss = true;
    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(disableUnlimitedLoss))
         isUnlimitedLoss = false; 
    System.out.println("deltaHedgeReque ;;;;;"+deltaHedgeReqd);
    boolean deltaHedge = Boolean.parseBoolean(deltaHedgeReqd)?true:false;
    System.out.println(" underlying name ::"+underlyingName);

    //underlyingList = getUnderlyingValues();
    //System.out.println("underlying " + underlyingList.get(0));
    //int maxLoss = accountList.get(0).getLossLimit().intValue();

    /**
     * If condition checks that user is coming for fresh case or overlay case by checking its previous combination. 
     * Taking positionCombinationArc list here , This list will return all d ex-positions of d user. 
     * this should b corrected to return only expiry month derviatives of d user.
     */
    try{    
        Set<String> underlyingSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        if(accountList!=null && accountList.size() != 0){
            List<PositionCombination> combinationsList = accountList.get(0).getAllPositions();

            List<PositionCombinationArc> combinationsArc = accountList.get(0).getAllPositionsArc();


            Map<String,List<PositionCombination>> combination =  new LinkedHashMap<String, List<PositionCombination>>();


            if(combinationsList !=null && combinationsList.size()>0){

                for(int i=0;i<combinationsList.size();i++){
                    List<PositionCombination> combinationNewList = new ArrayList<PositionCombination>();
                    combinationNewList.add(combinationsList.get(i));
                    List<AbstractPosition> abstractPositions = combinationsList.get(i).getPositions();
                    AbstractPosition abstractPosition = abstractPositions.get(0);
                    underlyingSet.add(abstractPosition.getUnderlyingName());
                     if (combination.containsKey(abstractPosition.getUnderlyingName())) {
                         List<PositionCombination> combinationCurrentList =combination.get(abstractPosition.getUnderlyingName());
                         combinationCurrentList.addAll(combinationNewList);
                         combination.put(abstractPosition.getUnderlyingName(), combinationCurrentList);


                     }else{
                         combination.put(abstractPosition.getUnderlyingName(), combinationNewList);
                     }

                }

                 if(combination.containsKey(underlyingName)){
                     List<PositionCombination> combinationCurrentList =combination.get(underlyingName);
                     strategyService.generateQuantReports(underlyingName, currentMonth, brokerageSlab,combinationCurrentList,combinationsArc,strategyType,investingAmount,selectedmonth,derivativeType,userlossLimit,riskRewardRatio,ulRangeFrom, ulRangeTo,otmSelected,expectedROI,maxNoLegsStrategy,isUnlimitedLoss,deltaHedge); 

                 }
                 else{
                     strategyService.generateQuantReports(underlyingName, currentMonth, brokerageSlab,strategyType,investingAmount,selectedmonth,derivativeType,userlossLimit,riskRewardRatio,ulRangeFrom, ulRangeTo,otmSelected,expectedROI,maxNoLegsStrategy, isUnlimitedLoss,deltaHedge,underlyingSet);
                 }
            }
            else
                strategyService.generateQuantReports(underlyingName, currentMonth, brokerageSlab,strategyType,investingAmount,selectedmonth,derivativeType,userlossLimit,riskRewardRatio,ulRangeFrom, ulRangeTo,otmSelected,expectedROI,maxNoLegsStrategy, isUnlimitedLoss,deltaHedge,underlyingSet);
                //strategyService.generateQuantReportsGivenLeg(underlyingName, currentMonth, brokerageSlab,strategyType,derivativeType);
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("hiii");
            strategyService.generateQuantReports(underlyingName, currentMonth, brokerageSlab,strategyType,investingAmount,selectedmonth,derivativeType,userlossLimit,riskRewardRatio,ulRangeFrom, ulRangeTo,otmSelected,expectedROI,maxNoLegsStrategy, isUnlimitedLoss,deltaHedge,underlyingSet);
            //strategyService.generateQuantReportsGivenLeg(underlying, currentMonth, brokerageSlab,strategyType);
            //strategyService.generatePremiumQuantReportsPremium(underlying, currentMonth, brokerageSlab);
            //generatePremiumPlayQuantReports

        }
        this.session.put("bestStrategies", strategyService);
        this.session.put("userName",user.getName());
        System.out.println("Exiting bestStrategies of BestStrategiesAction::");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        log.debug("Exception in best strategies " + user.getEmail() + " " + e.getMessage());
        return ERROR;
    }

}
```

This is my grid.jsp which is returned from the action class

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%--grid.locale-en.js to be loaded before jqGrid js --%> 
<%@ page import="com.uforic.optionstrader.domain.*,com.uforic.optionstrader.auth.OptionsUser,org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"%>
<%Userr user = ((OptionsUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserr();
user = Userr.findUserr(user.getId());
int userType = user.getUserType();
%>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/struts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OptionsTrader2/struts/js/plugins/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/OptionsTrader2/struts/themes/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<s:url id="remoteurl" value="strategyGrid"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function resizeJqGrid() {
        jQuery("#gridtable0").jqGrid('setGridWidth',$myLayout.state.center.innerWidth - 2 - 35, 'true');
    jQuery("#gridtable0").jqGrid('setGridHeight',$myLayout.state.center.innerHeight - 85, 'true');
};
 var analyseStrategyUrl = "analyseStrategyAction?";        //@tejas
 var selectedS;
 var createOrderUrl = "createOrderAction?";
 var submitOrderUrl = "submitOrderAction?";

 function onStrategySelect(id, status) {
$el = $("#radio3");
$el2 = $("#radio2");
if( $el.is(':checked') ) {
    selectedS = 'ivh'+id;
}
else if( $el2.is(':checked') ) {
    selectedS = 'grp'+id;
}
else {
 var dataFromCellByColumnIndex = jQuery('#gridtable0').jqGrid ('getCell', id,"unName");
    selectedS = "sid=stg"+id+"&unName="+dataFromCellByColumnIndex; //tejas
}
 function getCreateOrderUrl() {
  return createOrderUrl+selectedS;
 }

 function getSubmitOrderUrl(){
   //var quantity = 'qty'+document.getElementById('qty').value;
  return submitOrderUrl+selectedS;
  }

 function showGroupedStrategies() { 
 jQuery("#gridtable").setGridParam({url: 'groupedStrategyGrid'});
 jQuery("#gridtable").trigger("reloadGrid");
}

 function showListStrategies() {
  alert("show list strategies");
 jQuery("#gridtable").setGridParam({url: 'strategyGrid'});
 jQuery("#gridtable").trigger("reloadGrid");
  }

function showIvonhvStrategies() {
jQuery("#gridtable").setGridParam({url: 'ivonhvGrid'});
jQuery("#gridtable").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
 </script>
 <div style="height:0px">
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#radio").buttonset();
 $('[for=radio1], #radio1').click( function(event) {
     showListStrategies();
 });
$('[for=radio2], #radio2').click(function(event) {
    showGroupedStrategies();
});
$('[for=radio3], #radio3').click(function(event) {
    showIvonhvStrategies();
});
</script>

</div>
<table id="gridtable0" style="clear:both;" class="tablesorter"></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var userType = <%=userType%>;
var isUser = (userType==0)?true:false;
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    jQuery("#gridtable0").jqGrid({
        url:'strategyGrid',
        datatype: "json",
        height: '500',
        rownumbers: true,
        rowNum: 1000,
        cssClass: "ui-layout-content ui-widget-content",
        pager: false,
        scroll: true,
        loadonce: true, // to enable sorting on client side
        sortable: true, //to enable sorting
        cell:"",
        id:'0',

        colNames:['Trade', 'Expected Profit % p.a.','Profit Probability','Strategy Type','Max Profit %','Max Loss %','BreakEvenPoint 1', 'BreakEvenPoint 2', 'Investment %','Total Delta','Total Gamma','Total Theta','unName'],
            colModel:[
            {name:'optionDescription',index:'optionDescription', width:100},
            {name:'eplnppa',index:'eplnppa', sorttype:'float', width:50 , hidden: isUser},
            {name:'profprob',index:'profprob',sorttype:'float', width:50},
            {name:'strategytype',index:'strategytype',sorttype:'text', width:50},
            {name:'maxprofit',index:'maxprofit', sorttype:'float', width:50},
            {name:'maxloss',index:'maxloss', sorttype:'float', width:50},
            {name:'breakUpPoint1',index:'breakUpPoint1', width:50, sorttype:'text'},
            {name:'breakUpPoint2',index:'breakUpPoint2', width:50, sorttype:'text'},
            {name:'investmentpercentage',index:'investmentpercentage',width:50, hidden: isUser},
            {name:'delta',index:'delta',width:50},
            {name:'gamma',index:'gamma',width:50},
            {name:'theta',index:'theta',width:50},
            {name:'unName',index:'unName',width:50},

        ],
        sortname: 'epln',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        onSelectRow: onStrategySelect
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
resizeJqGrid();
</script>
```

This is my StrategyGrid class

```
 package com.uforic.optionstrader.action;
 import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
 import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
 import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;
 import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
 import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
 import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport; 
 @ParentPackage("layout")
 @Namespace("/m")
 public class StrategyGrid extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

Map session;
StrategyService strategyService;
String gridJson;

@Override
@Action(value = "strategyGrid", results = { @Result(location = "gridJson.jsp", name = "success") })
public String execute() {
    System.out.println("Strategy grid action called correctly");
    List<QuantReport> quantReports = getStrategies();
    this.gridJson = createGridJson(quantReports);
    System.out.println(" JSON CREATED :");
    return SUCCESS;
}

@Action(value = "groupedStrategyGrid", results = { @Result(location = "gridJson.jsp", name = "success") })
public String executeGroupedStrategyGridJson() {
    List<QuantReport> quantReports = getGroupedStrategies();
    this.gridJson = createGridJson(quantReports);
    return SUCCESS;
}

@Action(value = "ivonhvGrid", results = { @Result(location = "gridJson.jsp", name = "success") })
public String executeIvonhvGridJson() {
    List<QuantReport> quantReports = getIvonhvReports();
    this.gridJson = createGridJson(quantReports);
    return SUCCESS;
}

public List<QuantReport> getStrategies() {
    System.out.println("get strategies for current expiry date is called");
    List<QuantReport> quantReports = strategyService.getCurrentExpiryQuantReports();
    return quantReports;
}

public List<QuantReport> getGroupedStrategies() {
    List<QuantReport> quantReports = strategyService.getTopGroupedQuantReports();
    return quantReports;
}

public List<QuantReport> getIvonhvReports() {
    List<QuantReport> quantReports = strategyService.getIvOnHvQuantReports();
    return quantReports;
}

public String createGridJson(List<QuantReport> quantReports) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    Map<String, Object> grid = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    grid.put("page", "1");
    grid.put("total", "1");
    grid.put("records", quantReports.size());
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for(int i=0; i<quantReports.size(); i++) {
        CombiQuantReport report = (CombiQuantReport)quantReports.get(i);
        Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<String> cell = new ArrayList<String>();
        cell.add(report.getShortOptionDescription());
        cell.add(df.format(report.getEPLNPPA().doubleValue()));
        cell.add(df.format(report.getProfitProbability().doubleValue()));
        int k = report.identifyStrategy();
        String type = k == 0 ? "Neutral ": k == 1 ? "Volatile " : k == 2 ? "Bearish" : k == 3 ? "Bullish":"-";

        cell.add(type);

        String profitPerc = df.format((report.getMaxProfit().doubleValue()/report.getInvestmentAmountWithMargin().doubleValue())*100);
        cell.add(profitPerc);
        String lossPerc = df.format((report.getMaxLoss().doubleValue()/report.getInvestmentAmountWithMargin().doubleValue())*100);
        cell.add(lossPerc);
        cell.add(String.valueOf(k==2 && report.getActBreakEvenPoint2().intValue()==0?" ":(report.getBreakEvenSign1()== 0 ? "<":">")+" "+df.format(report.getActBreakEvenPoint1())));
        cell.add(String.valueOf(k==2 && report.getActBreakEvenPoint2().intValue()==0? "< "+df.format(report.getActBreakEvenPoint1()):report.getActBreakEvenPoint2().intValue() == 0 ? " " : ((report.getBreakEvenSign2()== 0 ? "<":">")+" "+df.format(report.getActBreakEvenPoint2()))));
        cell.add(df.format(report.getInvestmentPercentage()!=null?report.getInvestmentPercentage():BigDecimal.ZERO));//
        cell.add(getStrategyDelta(report));
        cell.add(getStrategyGamma(report));
        cell.add(getStrategyTheta(report));
        cell.add(report.getUnderlying());
        row.put("id", Integer.toString(i));
        row.put("cell", cell);
        rows.add(row);
    }
    grid.put("rows", rows);
    return JSONValue.toJSONString(grid);
}

public String getGridJson() {   
    return this.gridJson;
}

private String getStrategyDelta(CombiQuantReport report){

    DerivativeCombination combination = report.getOptionCombination();
    int numDerivatives = combination.numDerivatives();
    BigDecimal delta = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for(int i=0; i< numDerivatives; i++) {
        Derivative der = combination.getDerivative(i);
        QuantReport quantRep = report.forecast.getQuantReport(der);
        if(quantRep instanceof OptionQuantReport){
            OptionQuantReport optionReport = (OptionQuantReport)quantRep;
            delta = delta.add(optionReport.getDelta().setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(der.getContractSize() * der.getQty())));

        }

    }
    return delta.toString();
}

private String getStrategyGamma(CombiQuantReport report){
    DerivativeCombination combination = report.getOptionCombination();
    int numDerivatives = combination.numDerivatives();
    BigDecimal gamma = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for(int i=0; i< numDerivatives; i++) {
        Derivative der = combination.getDerivative(i);
        QuantReport quantRep = report.forecast.getQuantReport(der);
        if(quantRep instanceof OptionQuantReport){
            OptionQuantReport optionReport = (OptionQuantReport)quantRep;
            gamma = gamma.add((optionReport.getGamma().setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(der.getContractSize()*der.getQty()))));
        }

    }
    return gamma.toString();
}

private String getStrategyTheta(CombiQuantReport report){
    DerivativeCombination combination = report.getOptionCombination();
    int numDerivatives = combination.numDerivatives();
    BigDecimal theta = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for(int i=0; i< numDerivatives; i++) {
        Derivative der = combination.getDerivative(i);
        QuantReport quantRep = report.forecast.getQuantReport(der);
        if(quantRep instanceof OptionQuantReport){
            OptionQuantReport optionReport = (OptionQuantReport)quantRep;
            theta = theta.add((optionReport.getTheta().setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(der.getContractSize()*der.getQty()))));
        }

    }
    return theta.toString();
}

@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
    this.session = session;
    this.strategyService = (StrategyService)session.get("bestStrategies");
}
}
```